# Drain Terminal of a Multiplexer

Tags: voltage-divider, cmos, multiplexer

I am confused about some of the aspects of how a multiplexer works. In particular, I am working with an [ADG508A multiplexer](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/ADG508A_509A-878457.pdf). Looking at its functional block diagram (Fig 2, top panel, page 1) and the truth table (Table 5 of page 8), I am under the impression that the outputs of the pins S1--S4 may be governed by the binary inputs A1, A2, A0, and EN.

Does the functional diagram suggest that for any given combination of A1, A2, A0, and EN, the outputs of S1--S4 can also be affected by the input to the drain terminal D?

Also, what is the general purpose of a drain terminal D? Any explanation would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is and analog multiplexer or de-multiplexer. The drain (D) terminal and the source terminals (S) can be either analog inputs or analog outputs. An analog signal can trarvel from D to S or from S to D.

A0, A1, A2 and E control whether the path between S and D is high Z or low Z.

Addition to show the resistance profile for the analog switches,from the commwents.

[image]

Comment: Got it, thanks. Is there any mathematical relationship between the inputs/outputs of Ss and D?

Comment: It is a switch with a seriesresistance. Use a load resistance much much greater than the series resistance. Use the charts that show the resistance.

Comment: @rainman:  There are truth tables on pages 8 and 9 of the datasheet you linked that show the relation between the address inputs and the switch operation.

Comment: @RussellH: Which chart showing the resistance are you referring to?

Comment: @rainman: I have added the charts to the answer